# Delete transferred logs with logstash using sincedb, or use an alternative solution

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logging, logstash, bigdata

I want to move log files from a local directory to an `elasticsearch` client using `logstash`.

I want to remove the transferred logs (or alternatively alter their name),
in order to keep a reasonable log directory size.

I already understood that there's no built-in functionality in `logstash` for that, and I wondered if I can use the `sincedb` file to understand whether the file was completely processed and transferred, because I could also consider writing code which could handle that.

In case it is not possible, I'd could also use a completely different solution instead of `logstash`.

To sum it up:

- Is there a way to understand which files the `logstash` has finished processing using the `sincedb` file?
- If the answer to the previous question is no, is there another tool which could replace `logstash` in this case? I don't use any of the `logstash`'s parsing ability, only reading from local directory, and passing it to `elasticsearch`

Comment: You've listed a lot of your considerations nicely. But, what exactly are you asking in your question?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thank you, I added the questions explicitly

Answer (score 0):

The `%{path}` variable will have the file name from where the current event is read, if that helps.